# Error when editing variables of Gameoject script that are in array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, gameobject

in my code where it says "aICurrentLevel = go.GetComponent" I am getting an error back from MonoDevelop that says "This request is not supported by the protocol version implemented by the debuggee." Does anyone know why it is saying this? I have been digging around for a while on the internet to find that answer but can't seem to find it. All help is much appreciated. Overall what I am trying to do in this code is:

1. Add all game object with the tag "LadderPlacmentObject" into an array of Gameobjects.
2. Change the value of aICurrentLevel to the value found in the game object script.
3. If the game object is active and has the same level, show text in my console.

   ```
   void FindLadderObjects()
   {

   float aICurrentLevel;


   GameObject[] allLadderPlacmentObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("LadderPlacmentObject");
   foreach (GameObject go in allLadderPlacmentObjects) 
   {

       aICurrentLevel = go.GetComponent<LadderObjectInfo>().currentLevel;



           if (go.activeInHierarchy && aICurrentLevel == aILevel) 
       {

           Debug.Log ("Found some to move too");

       }

     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Please post your LadderObjectInfo script

Comment: https://fossies.org/linux/monodevelop/external/debugger-libs/Mono.Debugger.Soft/Mono.Debugger.Soft/VirtualMachine.cs Found reference to the exception in the Debuggers VM - Line 344 and 700 ish

Comment: Save me the work, an just comment out some bits of the line, and see when it stops working... :p Also, attach a basic component, and try to fetch that instead, to see if it works. In that case, its probably the other script.